# Div doesnt display right with position absolute

Tags: html, position, positioning, absolute

http://axol.de/HTML/Projects.html

On this page you can see that "Impressum" is in the middle of the page, instead of the bottom right. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

I dont want to add "height:100%" to my body, because then there is a scrollbar on the y axis for no reason...

How can I put it on the bottom page without having to give body any height?

Comment: Your "Impressum" will appear just at the right of your image. If you want it at the bottom right (under the image), you must delete your position and clear:both, and just add: float:right.
Like that, it's gonna appear on the bottom right. And just put a little margin-right

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you did not set the position of the `<div>`-Tag. And by default it is directly under the previous element.

Set as a footer (div):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

for your right alignment (div)

```
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
```

And for a little distance to the rigth border (a)

```
margin-right: 10px;
```

And by the way: you can hide scrollbars with `overflow:hidden` (body)

Edit:

```
<div ... style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; width:100%; text-align:right">
  ...
  <a ... style="margin-right:10px"></a>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I am using "position absolute" on the div tag... Why isnt that working? Do i really need two extra divs for just one word to be aligned on the bottom right?

Comment: Edit: I just noticed: When I put away "position:relative" from my body, it works... I dont know why... :-O

Comment: No extra `<div>`, you can change the CSS from the one `<div>` and for the distance of the border you can change the CSS of the `<a>`.